# Get result String RegEx

Tags: regex

I am trying to get string using RegEx; here is the string:

```
window.runParams = {};
window.runParams = {blablabla};
```

How to get the second string `{blablabla}`? I am using REGEX:

```
(?<=window.runParams = ").*(?=;)
```

But that gets the first string `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to get string with braces eg: {blablabla}

   window.runParams = ({\w+})
2. If you want to get only the string inside braces eg: blablabla

   window.runParams = {(\w+)}

Value of group 1 is your result

Answer (score 0):

try modifying your regex so it only accepts matches with non-empty curly brackets `\{.+\}` such as

```
(?<=window\.runParams = )(\{.+\})(?=;)
```

...there's probably ways to simplify the regex further, depending on you problem...my guess is you don't need the lookahead/lookbehind, e.g. in the example given `\{.+\}` will do just fine (returns `{blablabla}`) ....but it really depends on the format and content of your file...also remember braces, dots etc have a special meaning in regexes so you probably would want to escape them

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern captures only curly brackets with word character content:

```
(?<=window.runParams = ){\w+}(?=;)
```

and will only capture:

```
{blablabla}
```

when run against the text:

```
window.runParams = {};
window.runParams = {blablabla};
```

See results here:

https://regex101.com/r/mTwA64/1